# Which Android Gradle Plugin version should I use in my project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Which version should I use in my project?

I have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I`m using SDK 21 and Android Build Tools 21.0.2.

Answer (score 0):

0.13.3 is currently the latest version of the android gradle plugin.
You can find all release notes (including version numbers) here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system